# Uploads videos to Youtube programmatically

Tags: android, youtube-api, gdata-api

I'm trying to upload video to youtube programmatically. 
I tried with

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(clientID,developer_key);
service.setUserCredentials("email", "password");
```

But it throws ServiceException stating that
 `com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error connecting with login URI` 
How to proceed ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you didn't set up your authentication.

I suggest to use [Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). Here's a great java [UPLOAD](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/java/youtube-cmdline-uploadvideo-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/youtube_cmdline_uploadvideo_sample/UploadVideo.java) example.

I also open sourced an Android upload example ([YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/ytdl/ResumableUpload.java)) using ServiceIntent. Feel free to check it out.